# Git Move Ignored Files to Another Branch

Tags: eclipse, git

Scenario:

- There are several files on one branch (we'll call it `main` for now) that are in `.gitignore`. This is intentional; when these files are changed, the changes must not be seen by git in branch `main`
- These files are being tracked by another branch
- Periodically, after these files receive specific updates (but not the noisy, frequent updates they typically receive), the updates need to be pulled into the second branch

I see two potential solutions:

The first (and easiest, it seems) would be a command similar to git checkout, except that instead of pulling a file from a specified branch into the current, this command (let's call it `git-checkin`) would push a file from the current branch into the one branch specified. Does a command with the functionality of `git-checkin` exist?

Alternatively, is there a way to have git checkout another branch without overwriting any changes in the working directory, including those files that are being tracked (as if doing a partial merge)?

Comment: I'm curious what the underlying issue is. It sounds a bit like you have a set of configuration files on a "live" branch, and some template configuration files on master that occasionally get updated with e.g. an extra configuration parameter. I'm asking because perhaps there's another way to look at and solve the actual problem.

Comment: Effectively, this is very close. I am working to get Eclipse integrated with our development workflow. We have a large number of shared libraries, for which each gets a CDT project. These project files are frequently updated with useless information which detracts from the value of using SCM in the first place; however, for significant changes to the eclipse projects (such as the addition of references and what not), it would be incredibly helpful to track these changes and add them to the branch setup for storing Eclipse files.

Answer (score 0):

Current workaround:

- clone the repository to another directory (referred to as the `destination clone`)
- checkout the branch used for tracking the files in question in the `destination clone`
- in the `source clone` of the repo (with branch `main` checked out), use a script to copy the desired files from the `source clone` directories to the `destination clone` directories

I'm guessing that a `git-checkin` does not exist; if anyone has some better suggestions then they are welcome!